# Open and display chrome from shell executable

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-18.04

I would like to open a URL that is located in a variable ('URL') with Chrome.
I have the following code:

```
$nohup google-chrome --no-sandbox $URL &
```

The problem is that this code uses --no-sandbox making Chrome to crash after I try to open it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xargs bash -c 'nohup  google-chrome --no-sandbox $@ &' null  < tabs.txt
```

With a tests file like this:

```
$ cat tabs.txt                                         
https://stackoverflow.com
unix.stackexchange.com
```

**Method2**:

if your browser is chrome and your script openurl is

```
#!/bin/bash
chrome "$1"
```

Run it like

```
./openurl "https://stackoverflow.com"
```

Note:
Replace chrome with your browser

**Method3**

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser chromium-browser.desktop
```

or

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser chromium-browser.desktop
```

then

```
xdg-open https://stackoverflow.com
```